# Ruby on Rails log4r and rabbitMQ Custom Outputter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, log4r

I am trying to create a custom outputter that logs remotely using a message queue...
I found an outputter in the log4r project and tried to modify it... but i suck... so there is likely a WAY better way to do this. i.e.: one that works. ;)

Here i create my duplicate outputter with modified inatializer and write methods.

**/lib/rabbit_outputter.rb**

```
require 'log4r'
require 'bunny'

class RabbitOutputter < Log4r::Outputter
  attr_reader :host, :port
  attr_accessor :udpsock
  @exchange = "test1"

  def initialize(_name, hash={})
   super(_name, hash)

   bunny = Bunny.new
   bunny.start
   q = bunny.queue(@exchange)
   @e = bunny.exchange("")
   @e.publish("BOOSH!", :key => @exchange)
   #uncomment this later... b.stop

  end

  #######
  private
  #######

  def write(data)  
    @e.publish(data, :key => @exchange)
  end

end
```

Then i mixed it into my rails initializers. 
**/config/initalizers/rabbit_outputter.rb**

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/rabbit_outputter.rb"
```

Then i swap out my log4r loggers in my log4r.yaml file

**/config/log4r.yaml**

```
log4r_config:
  loggers:
    - name : development
      level : DEBUG
      additive : 'false'
      trace : 'true'
      outputters:
      - rabbit_outputter
    - name : test
      level : DEBUG
      additive : 'false'
      trace : 'true'
      outputters:
      - rabbit_outputter
    - name : staging
      level : INFO
      additive : 'false'
      trace : 'true'
      outputters:
      - rabbit_outputter
    - name : production
      level : INFO
      additive : 'false'
      trace : 'true'
      outputters:
      - rabbit_outputter
  outputters:
    - type : RabbitOutputter
      name : rabbit_outputter
      level : INFO
      filename : <%= "#{Rails.root}/log/#{Rails.env}.log" %>
      formatter:
        date_pattern: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
        pattern : '{ \"date\":\"%d\", \"level\":\"%l\", \"appname\":\"MyApp\", \"event fullname\": \"%C\", \"global_diagnostic_context\":\"%g\",\"trace\":\"%t\", \"message\": %m }'
        type : PatternFormatter
```

Here is the error when i open a rails console:

```
rails c
/Users/<myusername>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/yamlconfigurator.rb:68:in `block in decode_yaml': 
Problem creating outputter: uninitialized constant Log4r::RabbitOutputter (Log4r::ConfigError)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and was able to solve it by putting the following code at the top of my application.rb, after my Bundler.require statement:

```
require 'log4r'
require 'log4r/yamlconfigurator'
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/rollable_file_outputter.rb"
include Log4r
```

Then, at the bottom on the Application class block, add this and with dynamic loggers:

```
# Assign log4r's logger as Rails' logger.
log4r_config= YAML.load_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"../log4r.yml"))
YamlConfigurator.decode_yaml( log4r_config['log4r_config'] )
Server::Application::config.logger = Log4r::Logger[Rails.env]
```

Then I could use `type: RollableFileOutputter` in my `config/log4r.yml` file.

I tried putting all this into a single initializer (`config/initializers/logging.rb`), but then the default logger was not log4r, just the standard rails logger.  I don't really understand why.

Comment: This led me to the solution to another problem I was having. Using EmailOutputter in an XML config only works if you add require 'log4r/emailoutputter' in application.rb